# Is it possible to use Unity8 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, unity8

I've tried:

> ```
> unknownlinux@UnknownLinux:~$ sudo apt install unity8-desktop-session-mir
> A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
> A construir árvore de dependências       
> A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
> E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote unity8-desktop-session-mir
> ```

If it isn't possible, should I use Ubuntu 17.10, or Ubuntu 17.04 with unity8?

Comment: Given your username, you probably should not be trying to run Unity 8. It never matured to the point of being able to replace Unity 7, is not a stable and reliable environment, and has been abandoned by Canonical (along with Unity 7).

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to run the Unity 8 desktop on 17.10. You need 17.04 or 16.04 LTS.

**EDIT:**
Unity 8 is not in the 17.10 repository's, and Unity 7 is in Universe now and will be removed in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: But if i can have Unity7 why i can't Unity8? XD                                                                 Also: If: Isn't possible, should i use ubuntu 17.10, or ubuntu 17.04 with unity8?

Comment: 17.10 is running a GNOME desktop. You need to use 17.04 or 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Right, ur right Bevan 17.10 its using GNOME desktop, but u still can install Unity7 and login with Unity7 from login screen, so why we can't install unity8 and login with it? XD also can you reply to this? Should i use ubuntu 17.10, or ubuntu 17.04 with unity8

Comment: Because unity8 was removed from the archive, and unity7 was only moved into universe. In 18.04 unity7 should also get removed from the archive. There is no more unity8. There is a PPA for yunit I believe, but I don't recall which versions of Ubuntu it supports.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to have this new information. :)

Comment: There is no indication unity7 is being removed from disk